# Эффект матового стекла CSS, размывающий контент

Tags: css, frontend

Как сделать сам эффект я знаю, но стандартные решения на blur размывают изображения заднего фона, мне же нужно, чтоб размывало еще и сам контент

Сейчас так:

[image]

Нужно так:

[image]

Comment: Не понял, в чём оказалась проблема применить blur к контенту?

Comment: Проблема такова, способ с blur не размывает контент позади панели, а лишь изображения https://yadi.sk/i/C53YT7wM3NBkFQ.

Comment: Что-то вы очень криво изъясняетесь, я вас так и не понял. Попробую угадать: вам нужно вот так? https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrFHs.png

Comment: Да, именно так. Простите за неясный вопрос

Comment: Пока это невозможно сделать с помощью css или даже js

Comment: Спасибо, использую ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @Александр такое размытие нужно применить лишь в каком-то определенном месте на сайте? Есть один вариант на js/jquery, но хотелось бы увидеть вашу разметку

Comment: В Нескольких местах, нужен своеобразный KIT. Я думал SVG справится, но увы, спасибо за уделенное время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока это невозможно сделать с помощью css или даже js - [Duoxx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/245150/duoxx)